# Handling Ctrl+C with Win32

Tags: winapi, keyboard-events

I have a Win32 window message loop. I want to intercept "Copy to clipboard" via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
My current approach is to handle it like this:

```
...
case WM_KEYDOWN:
   TranslateMessage(&message);

   // Intercept Ctrl+C for copy to clipboard
   if ('C' == message.wParam && (::GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL)>>15))
   { // do the copy... }
...
```

Is there a better way to do this other than explicitly checking for the key-stroke combination?

Is there some way to register the *standard* copy-to-clipboard keystroke and then handle a `WM_COPY` message?

Comment: Keep in mind a user can use Ctrl+Insert instead of Ctrl+C.

Comment: The usual solution is to create an accelerator table and use `TranslateAccelerator` in your message loop.  This gives you a `WM_COMMAND` rather than `WM_COPY`, but this is no bad thing because it matches what you get from the Edit|Copy menu item.  As far as I know, "Ctrl+C" is never localized.

Comment: Why are you calling TranslateMessage in the handler?  It doesn't actually modify the message, it posts additional messages to the queue.  The normal way to use it is to put it in the message loop.  If you only let it see the WM_KEYDOWNS, I don't think it's going to work.

Comment: @arx: Yes, but is it reall worth setting up and managing a full accelerator table, when all I need to to handle Ctrl+C, especially when I already have a `WM_KEYDOWN` handler and Ctrl+C is never localized? Is there any advantage to using the accelerator table?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: I'm adding clipboard support to existing code. There's more stuff happening after `TranslateMessage()` that isn't relevant to my question.

Comment: @AdiShavit The advantages are that it's standard (and hence readable) and conveniently localizable.  For a single accelerator that doesn't get localized it probably is more trouble than it's worth.  Since this is the standard way of doing it, there probably isn't another mechanism that does exactly what you want (i.e. translate "Ctrl+C" to WM_COPY).

Comment: @arx: For now it's just the one hotkey, and my project doesn't even have a resource file, so for now I think I'll stick with what I have. Thanks.

Comment: @AdiShavit:  My point was that TranslateMessage doesn't belong in a handler, it belongs in the message loop.

Comment: If your application has more than one window that might want to handle a copy operation, then you probably want to interpret the keypress in the message loop and translate it to copy message that's sent to the window with focus (which is basically how accelerator tables are used).  If you just care about the one window, you can certainly check for the keypress in the WM_KEYDOWN handler.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Yes, that's basically what I'm doing. At the point of interception, in the message loop, I already have the correct window `hWnd` and I post the `WM_COPY` message to that window.

Comment: @AdiShavit:  The code you posted doesn't look like part of the message loop.  It looks like a window procedure (message handler).  TranslateMessage belongs in the loop, not the handler.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Hmmm... I'm actually updating some existing open source [code in the OpenCV library](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/modules/highgui/src/window_w32.cpp#L1716) (see [line 1757](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/modules/highgui/src/window_w32.cpp#L1757)).

Comment: @AdiShavit:  OK, that is in the message loop, because they're doing some special processing.  It's certainly not the "typical message loop" claimed in the problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

Windows treats <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> as one key in the `WM_CHAR` message.

```c
enum
{
 CTRL_BASE  = 'A' - 1,
 SELECT_ALL = 'A' - CTRL_BASE, // Ctrl+A
 COPY       = 'C' - CTRL_BASE, // Ctrl+C
 CUT        = 'X' - CTRL_BASE, // Ctrl+X
 PASTE      = 'V' - CTRL_BASE, // Ctrl+V
 UNDO       = 'Z' - CTRL_BASE, // Ctrl+Z
 REDO       = 'Y' - CTRL_BASE, // Ctrl+Y
};
```

Note: This is not documented at [MSDN - WM_CHAR message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-char). This is an observation I made while creating my text editor. Although `Ctrl+A == 0x41` is mentioned in [Keyboard Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/keyboard-input#character-messages).

Using `WM_CHAR` instead of manually handling `WM_KEYDOWN`, etc makes processing closer to the standard, specifically does auto-repeat when a key is held, and does not emit the message when extra keys are held.

Apparently there's no readily available way to have `WM_COPY` delivered for you instead of keys.

Comment: It might be more clear this way:   `enum { CTRL_BASE = 'A'-1,  SELECT_ALL = 'A' - CTRL_BASE,  COPY = 'C' - CTRL_BASE, CUT = 'X' - CTRL_BASE }`, etc

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think this might be a better answer if you add that you are not aware of standard way to have Ctrl-C done by the system for you, and clarify why you think relying on `Ctrl-C == 3` as `WM_CHAR` is better than handling `WM_KEYDOWN` / `WM_KEYUP`

Comment: @Alex I did put a note at the end that this is not documented. Also, your CTRL_BASE idea, I never had a clue about. I just copied the integers I saw. Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Nice, I noticed this `CTRL+X` behaviour too. Gonna use this undocumented stuff in my own text editor too!

Comment: The way it works, is actually mapping `CTRL+X` combo to the command characters at the beginning of ASCII table. So, `CTRL+C` becomes `ETX` (0x3) and `CTRL+V` becomes `SYN` (0x16), `CTRL+X` becomes `CAN` (0x18). If you press `CTRL+G` you get to listen to a nice `BEL` sound ;)

Comment: This method has one little inconvenience, though. You can't really make accelerator for `CTRL+H/J/M/I` and some other characters. This combination maps to the commonly used control chars - H -> Backspace, J -> Newline, M -> Carriage Return, I -> Horizontal Tab, etc.