# Why `WM_CHAR` sends keys combinations and is it safe to use them?

Tags: winapi

I am writing an input field control and currently have developed `ctrl`+`c` and `ctrl`+`v` logic.

I know that there is `WM_KEYDOWN`, but I notice (long before) that `WM_CHAR` actually gives different `WPARAM` values when I press, for example, `c` key on the keyboard, depending on have I pressed `ctrl`. And of course it is way more easier to deal with, instead of handling whether `ctrl` was pressed or released using `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP`.

What is confusing me is, obviously why it happens in `WM_CHAR` at all, and most important the `WPARAM` value itself - if I just press `c` it is 99, which is [correct](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html), and if I press `c` with `ctrl` pressed it is 3 which is `ETX (end of text)`.

So can be there a case when, say, depending on the keyboard layout (although I tested for eng, ru and ua - all the same), `WM_CHAR` will have not 3 in `WPARAM` for `ctrl`+`c`?

Comment: `WM_KEY(DOWN|UP)` gives you the individual events for *virtual key codes*, whereas `WM_CHAR` gives you the *translated characters* that are based on the keyboard state when the up|down events are processed. `'c'` and `Ctrl-C` are different characters from different keyboard states. And AFAIK, Ctrl-C will always be the `ETX` character.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So it is safe in `WM_CHAR` check `if(wparam == 3)` to check if `ctrl`+`c` is pressed, for example?

Comment: See [Handling Ctrl+C with Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005661/), particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70232870/65863)

Comment: @RemyLebeau, nice